# Updating row from select results

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am on a project of which requires Ranking and outputing the total score to users.

I have a table called `userdata` like this

```
    id  matricno    mtstotal    engtotal    grandtotal  Rank

    1   MXX001      6           4           
    2   MXX002      9           8           
    3   MXX003      5           3           
    4   MXX004      4           7           
    5   MXX005      7           2           


    SELECT * FROM (
      SELECT s.*, @rank := @rank + 1 rank FROM (
        SELECT matricno, sum(mtstotal + engtotal) TotalPoints FROM userdata
        WHERE class='1' AND subclass='A'
        GROUP BY matricno
      ) s, (SELECT @rank := 0) init
      ORDER BY TotalPoints DESC
    ) r
```

This SQL creates something temporary

```
    matricno    TotalPoints rank

    MXX002      17          1           
    MXX004      11          2           
    MXX001      10          3           
    MXX005      9           4           
    MXX003      8           5
```

What I want is a statement added to the one above that will copy the TotalPoints and rank values and update the grandtotal and Rank columns respectively.
Even if it is formatting another code but it should be able to sum, rank and update in one single coding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When updating `userdata` join it with your query as subselect and use values from it

```sql
UPDATE userdata ud
JOIN(
  SELECT s.*, @rank := @rank + 1 rank FROM (
    SELECT matricno, sum(mtstotal + engtotal) TotalPoints FROM userdata
    WHERE class='1' AND subclass='A'
    GROUP BY matricno
  ) s, (SELECT @rank := 0) init
  ORDER BY TotalPoints DESC
) r ON r.matricno = ud.matricno
SET ud.grandtotal = r.TotalPoints,
    ud.Rank       = r.rank
```

Comment: This works very fine. Thanks!